# Separate logic from view in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and web development as well.

Here is sample code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var app = angular.module('app', []);

  app.controller("controller", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.doClick = function() {
      alert("alert!");
    }
  });
</script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
  <button ng-click="doClick()">Button</button>
</body>
```

This is pretty simple code but working for a while on my app I noticed that my HTML page is gradually cluttering with texts like `ng-click="doClick()"`, `ng-click="doAnotherClick()"`, `ng-change="doChange()"` and so on.

So the view is mixed up with logic.

Maybe this is pretty usual practice but I wonder is there any way to move all information about what events should be handled and how they should be handled to a distinct script tag or file?

What I want to get is something like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var app = angular.module('app', []);

  // Binding event handlers
  //
  // Something like the following imagined code:
  //
  // element(".myButton").bind("click", function(element) {
  //    doClick();
  // });


  app.controller("controller", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.doClick = function(element) {
      alert(element.somedata);
    }
  });
</script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
  <button class="myButton">Button</button>
</body>
```

In other words I want to replace event handler names with id's and classes.

Also, in event handler (doClick) I want to have access to any data of element fired an event (ex. data stored in ng-model associated with element).

Comment: what you're looking for is a directive ... thats how you correctly manipulate the DOM in angularjs....https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: That's not "the angular way" of doing it. The whole point of Angular is to make the markup smarter, thus allowing things like ng-click, ng-change etc. Using jQuery bindings is not how you should be doing it, as it contradicts everything Angular is about.

Comment: not entirely correct.... he is more than welcome to use directives and bind events... there is NO reason not to... actually for DOM manipulation it actually makes more sense than calling your controller....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can replace you event handler with id's or classes with the use od querySelector on the document load. for reffe. use this link

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp
and

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

i can do code for you if you provide me plnkr of your code. but i think it is simple you can do it. i hope it will help you.

Comment: W3 schools is not a good reference, and using querySelector (or jqLite, which is built into Angular) is not Angular best practice.

Comment: i have updated one more best link for the querySelector. and yes i have posted my best if you know/want to add something more as the answer you can edit my answer or either posted a new answer. suggestions are always welcome and yes my answer is not too bad that you downvote my answer is't it ? by the way thanks